# Sending data to via AJAX to WP Plugin - maximum recommended size?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm writing a WP plugin that can potentially attempt to send large amounts of data to the plugin's PHP file with an AJAX POST request. The amount of data will vary based on user's actions, so I want to make sure all data reaches the PHP. Until this point I've had multiple reports from clients that data is being truncated. Sometimes increasing the `post_max_size` helps, sometimes it doesn't.

The solution that I'm trying to implement in order to send unlimited amount of data is to split the POST request into pieces (it's just a JSON) and send them one by one. My question is how large should I make those pieces in terms of number of characters to be safe?

I'm thinking about 4096, which is 4KB.

Thanks

**I can't make changes to the server settings! This plugin will be used by many clients and I don't have control over their servers.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if it's a large number of items or if it's just a large data item (e.g. a file upload).

If it's the former then I've seen this before. It's very likely to be `max_input_vars` which defaults to 1000. Change it in your php.ini to something higher, and that should fix it.

http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Comment: I'm sending just a few variables, the problem is that one of those variables can be a very long string.